# Errors when attempting to create an object with a constructor

Tags: c++

I'm new to object orientated programming in c++ and have been trying to create an object for a graph problem. I have googled the errors in the situation they occur to no avail - mainly results about constant functions. My code is below and I have written the errors as inline comments where they appear

`#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Graph {                   //'Graph' cannot be defined in the result type of a function
    public:
        Graph(int n);
    private:
        std::vector<std::list<int> > Connections;
}

Graph::Graph(int n) {           //constructor cannot have a return type
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++){
         x=1 //placeholder, intended to fill vectors with linked lists
    }
}

Graph g = new Graph(10);`

I am not quite sure why any of these problems occur and would be extremely grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class needs a `;` after the terminating `}` . There's also one missing after the `x=1`.

Comment: C++ is not Java. `Graph g(10);`.

Comment: `x` is undeclared. That's a no no in C++. What exactly is it placeholding?

Comment: What errors are you asking about specifically?

Comment: Try to better describe what you are trying to do.  Why are you passing a 10 into graph and what does it represent?  

It seems you are trying to create a graph class but have it execute like a function.  Is there a particular reason you need it to be an object?

Also is the Graph in public supposed to be a function?  If so you need to determine a return type or void.

Comment: @Wollzy the `Graph(int n);` and `Graph::Graph(int n)` is a constructor, it doesn't need a return type.

Comment: ***What errors are you asking about specifically?*** In this case there are 2 errors marked as comments in the code. I am sure @Steve has the reason. This question probably should be closed as a typo. or even a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Graph {                  
    public:
        Graph(int n);
    private:
        std::vector<std::list<int> > Connections;
};

Graph::Graph(int n) {     
    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++){
         int x=1; 
    };
};

int main(){
   Graph *g = new Graph(10);
};
```

If this is too cluttered use header files.

Also when allocating a new object you need to use a pointer as you are dynamically allocating with new.

Also you were missing semicolons per @Steve comment

Comment: You don't _need_ to define the entire constructor inside the class, you only need to declare it (although you certainly _can_ do)

Comment: @Steve true.  Figured for such a small constructor is would make the code more readable

Comment: But there was nothing wrong with that part of the code in the question, and your statement is misleading. By all means suggest that small methods be defined inside the class, just don't tell him that he must do it :)

Comment: @Steve I'm an idiot.  i missed your comment above about the missing semicolon he had.  I assumed the issue was the way he declared his constructor.  My mistake.  Edited my answer.